# Why can't the SQL contains predicate be shortcut using an is null

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, full-text-search

I get the error `Null or empty full-text predicate.` for the query

```
declare @searchTerm varchar(50) = null
select * 
from Products 
where @searchTerm is null or contains(Details, @searchTerm)
```

Why is this? I was hoping the `is null` condition will shortcut the `contains`.

This is how the table is prepared

```
create table Products (Id int identity(1,1), Details varchar(500))
alter table Products add constraint PK_Products primary key clustered (Id asc)
create fulltext catalog ProductsFTS
create fulltext index on Products (Details) key index PK_Products on ProductsFTS
```

And the SQL Server version - `Microsoft SQL Server 2019 (RTM-GDR) (KB4583458) - 15.0.2080.9 (X64)   Nov  6 2020 16:50:01   Copyright (C) 2019 Microsoft Corporation  Developer Edition (64-bit) on Windows 10 Enterprise 10.0 <X64> (Build 19044: )`

Worth noting that I managed to work around the issue, following the answer here - https://stackoverflow.com/a/3411391/1355646

Comment: I don't see anywhere in your original code where you are setting the @searchTerm variable, and your WHERE clause never references a column in the table, so if you replace the variable in your select statement with the value you've set it up with you get:

`select * 
from Products 
where null is null or contains(Details, null)`

Comment: @AnthonyNorwood totally agree, but then when the `null is null` part evaluates to `true`, why bother with the other part of the `or`? (My requirement is for the query to return all possible results if no search term is specified)